# Catch the relational operators with regex

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

```
5 * ( {0,0} + {0,1} ) >= 4 * ( {0,2} / {0,3} )
```

I managed to get the left and right parts of the string; relational operator in this case **>=**

I used in order to get **+,-,*,/** operators:

```
[\+\-\*/]
```

for **{0,0}** pairs:

```
\{\d*,\d*\}
```

There is one single part left I stuck: to get relational operators which are:
**<,>,<=,>=,==,!=**

Can anyone help me to write the regex for it?

Comment: How about `[<>=!]=?`?

Comment: Thanks a million. If you can write it as answer, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to match **<,>,<=,>=,==,!=**

```
[<>=!]=?
```

This matches other combinations too, for example `=` and `!`. To ensure that it *only* matches the required patterns you could use:

```
(?:<=?|>=?|==|!=)
```

This is a little less concise and may not be necessary.

Comment: Just to note that it also matches `=`, `!`.

Comment: Actually this match to '!' as well. So ([<>]=?|[!=]=) fits better, I suppose.